# Difference between 彫る【ほる】 (horu) and 刻む【きざむ】 (kizamu)

Tags: words

As I see it right now they both mean: to carve;  to engrave, to chisel;  to notch.

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「[掘]{ほ}る」 actually does ***not*** mean "to carve", "to engrave" or "to chisel".  Instead, it means "to dig (up)".

> 「[穴]{あな}を掘る」 = "to dig a hole"
>
> 「いもを掘る」 = "to dig up potatoes"

You are probably thinking of 「[彫]{ほ}る」, which means what you stated.

> 「メダルに[名前]{なま}を彫る」 = "to engrave one's name on a medal"
>
> 「[仏像]{ぶつぞう}を彫る」 = "to carve a Buddha"

Traditionally, 「彫る」 has another important meaning which is "to tattoo".

「[刻]{きざ}む」 can mean "to carve", "to engrave", etc., but its primary meaning is "to cut into pieces", "to chop", etc.

> 「刻みキャベツ」 = "shredded cabbage"

Comment: I'm sorry. you are right, i accidentaly write wrote kanji in there and i meant 彫る. i have changed the questiong and thanks for your answer.